# Expect-lite: very simple script failing on trivial C++ program

Tags: automated-tests, expect

I'm trying to learn how to automate CLI programs using [expect-lite](http://expect-lite.sourceforge.net/) . However, after a few hours reading documentation, I’m still failing to execute a very simple script to test a trivial C++ program I made. I’m using cygwin to run expect-lite on windows. My program only receives a user input and prints something in return:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string command;
    cout << "Input command:\n";
    cin >> command;
    if (command=="continue")
        cout << "We shall continue";
    else
        cout << "The end";
    return 0;
}
```

And my expect-lite script looks like this:

```
> ./myprogram
< Input command:
>> continue
< We shall continue
```

But the output I get is the following:

```
$ ./expect-lite -c testing.elt
Warning: Remote Host=none, using Localhost
spawn bash

hp@hp-HP ~/expect-lite.proj
$
hp@hp-HP ~/expect-lite.proj
$
hp@hp-HP ~/expect-lite.proj
$
hp@hp-HP ~/expect-lite.proj
$ PS1="[\u@\h:\w]\$ "
[hp@hp-HP:~/expect-lite.proj]$
[hp@hp-HP:~/expect-lite.proj]$  ./myprogram
Input command:
Waiting: ....+....
FAILED COMMAND: ./myprogram

    Expect Failed: Input command:
exit
The end[hp@hp-HP:~/expect-lite.proj]$
##Overall Result: FAILED

hp@hp-HP ~/expect-lite.proj
```

I only tried this very simple script on a very simple program as a starting point, but I'm not getting it to work. Any ideas on why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, an easy solution to a simple program: I was using extra spaces in my expect-lite script.
I solved the problem by removing them:

```
>./myprogram
<Input command:
>>continue
<We shall continue
```

Now I'm getting a "Warning, prompt timed out between "Input command:" and "continue" but I'll figure it out. Test is passing now.